# Is there an enum that holds the runtime's type encoding characters?

Tags: objective-c, encoding, objective-c-runtime

Objective-C uses single-letter type encoding for primitives; for example, `'c'` is `char`, `'i'` is `int`. These are documented in the Obj-C Runtime Reference.

Is there an existing `enum` that models these?

Comment: It doesn't use single letters, @encode returns a string and for example void* is encoded to "^v".

Comment: What should be the purpose of such enum? Provide identifiers for types whose encodings happen to be single letter?

Comment: @Ramy - That's a single letter for to indicate a pointer and another single letter for the primitive type. . . structs, unions and arrays indeed use more letters though.

Comment: @Nikolai - It's part of a TypeDescriptor class that I'm writing for an app that uses some runtime introspection. . Other attributes of the class are BOOL isPrimitive BOOL isArray, BOOL isPointer, etc. . .

Comment: I just realized that I completely misunderstood your question and that my answer is totally off the mark. Please "unaccept" the answer so that I can delete it.

Comment: @herzbube - WTF happened there?!? I just re-read your answer and realized that I'd completely mis-understood that too! What I "read" was that there isn't an enum representing the various obj primitives. . . must be holiday season! ;)

Comment: @user404201 I said that even a string of one character is still considered a string. And a pointer to void has type pointer to void, I don't know why you split it's type in two.

Comment: @Ramy Understood, I was just playing the fool with that comment :) I "split" it into two as part of the parsing process to make a type descriptor class. . . https://github.com/jasperblues/spring-objective-c/blob/master/Source/TypeConversion/SpringTypeDescriptor.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such `enum`. The encodings are initially built by the compiler, which simply has the literal strings embedded in its code. You can see them in [`ASTContext.cpp`](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/AST/ASTContext.cpp?view=markup), specifically the methods `getObjCEncodingForTypeImpl()` and `getObjCEncodingForPrimitiveKind()`.

The [runtime library](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/) has a set of functions, in [objc-typeencoding.mm](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/objc-typeencoding.mm) that read these strings. You can use these yourself; that code is available under Apple's open source license. (The compiler's `ASTContext` also has a method to do this, `DecodeTypeFromStr()`.)

Obviously the runtime and the compiler have to stay in sync as far as these encodings. In fact, since changing the encoding character for a type would create binary incompatibility, it's unlikely to happen at all, and certainly not without notice; you can rely on the list in the Runtime Guide to be stable.

That's not to say things won't be added, of course: `"@?"` is the encoding string for a Block, which didn't exist before they were introduced (although it's similar to/derived from the `"^?"` that denotes a function pointer).

You may also be interested in Mike Ash's [article about linking up libffi and Blocks](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-05-06-a-tour-of-mablockclosure.html), in which he demonstrates [a series of macros](https://github.com/mikeash/MABlockClosure/blob/master/MABlockClosure.m#L119) to read an encode string and
produce its real type.